# Angular Datatables with *ngIf shows error

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using [Angular Datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) to show some tabular data. I have added an `*ngIf` condition to the table, so that it will not be visible until the data is loaded completely. The table code looks like the following :

```
<table class="table" id="releaseDatatable" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" *ngIf="!loading">
```

The `loading` variable I am setting from my component and then calling `this.dtTrigger.next()`. I have the following code to set `loading`.

```
set loading(loading: boolean) {
        this._loading = loading;
       setTimeout(()=>{
            this.dtTrigger.next();
       }, 100);
    }
```

Now for the first time, everything is working fine. But when I try to re-load the table (after edit or delete), it it is showing the following error :

```
ERROR ObjectUnsubscribedErrorImpl {message: "object unsubscribed", name: "ObjectUnsubscribedError"}
```

and `this.dtTrigger` has `null` as observers. How this can be fixed ? I tried to re-render the table, but it is also not working.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `[ngClass]` and hide rather than using `ngIf`

```
<table class="table" id="releaseDatatable" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" [ngClass]="loading">
```

in component make loading attribute as "hide" or "show";

in css hide it

```
.hide{
   display:none;
}
```

For render again I use destroy and and trigger next

import

```
  import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective, {static: false})  
   datatableElement: DataTableDirective;
```

to render

```
rerender(){
        this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
            dtInstance.destroy();
            this.dtTrigger.next();
        });       
    }
```

call this rerender method

```
set loading(loading: boolean) {
       setTimeout(()=>{
            this.rerender();
       }, 100);
    }
```

Comment: I think the issue is that `ngIf` removes the table from DOM and so for the second time, It is not able trigger the table reload. But no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @HappyCoder yes you are right. You can use class rather than ngIf as a way . I update answer with this approach

Comment: That also will not work. It is showing `DataTables warning: table id=releaseDatatable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3`

Comment: This is rerender problem . I updated answer to rerender table . I firstly destroy then I trigger next @HappyCoder

Comment: Unfortunately, it is also not working It shows `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
 `

Comment: Did you import import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables'; in component

Comment: Can you check this rerender https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem with how Angular Datatables re-renders

You can find more details and workarounds from the GitHub issues list e.g. https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1241

Some of the comments suggest using `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`

Comment: Any workaround ? I tried to use the `hidden` mentioned there, but it is showing error `DataTables warning: table id=releaseDatatable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3`

Comment: Yes. But don't have any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to add a wrapper div for your table like `<div *ngIf="!loading"><table></table></div>`

Angular v2 doesn't support more than one structural directive on the same element.